# How to I make the white background and white text of this logo (.psd) transparent?

Tags: logo, transparency

￼[image: product logo]

Hiya, I've been asked to do a quick fix (although I'm no expert!) to change the white parts of this logo transparent. I have a .psd version of it and it looks like it's all one layer. I'm afraid thats all I know! Any suggestions on how I can change the white parts to transparent? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the layer is unlocked. Right click the layer, and select blending options from the menu. On the "This Layer:" blending bar, move the right slider to the left just a tiny bit, and all the white from that layer should become transparent.

[image]

Comment: That's a great trick! My only comment is that it does leave a residual outline (colour on white) due to anti-aliasing. Once you've done it, though, Ctrl Click the layer and feather by 1 px, then delete a couple of times. That should remove the edge.